# Getting regex to output a fixed string as group 1

Tags: regex

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a regular expression that will output a fixed string like 'bla' as group #1 regardless of the input string?

I'm using a library method to get the username from a string via a regex match. The used regex is the only variable I can give to that method, the input string is always the same and in this particular situation does not contain the needed output string.

Comment: Why not just add it to the result afterwards? This sounds suspiciously like a XY problem - please see: [**what is the XY problem?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Short answer: No. Regexes can only match existing text, not create new text. Of course you can use callback methods to manipulate the match results, if your regex engine supports them, but a) it's not the regex anymore that's doing this and b) @h2ooooooo is probably right about the XY problem.

Comment: I'm using the same library method for different situations. The regex is the only variable I can send with it. And in this particular situation I need it to always return the same fixed string.

Comment: @RickBrunken Have you thought about just adding that certain fixed string to the input beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, some time ago I happened to ask Jan Goyvaerts, who is the author of RegexBuddy and knowledgeable about a myriad regex flavors, whether he happened to know a regex flavor that allows inserting arbitrary text in the replacement—not as a callback or lambda. For instance, a conditional allowing you to insert `foo` when Group 1 is matched. Or a trick to capture text that isn't there, perhaps with some kind of weird lookaround-fu. He replied that he does not know any flavor allowing this. I believe this is what you were looking for.

I'm sure you're aware that programming languages allow you to manipulate your replacement text in anonymous functions and callbacks... But that's doesn't seem to be what you were after.

Comment: This sounds indeed exactly as what I'm looking for. Too bad it seems like it cannot be done...

Comment: @RickBrunken Yes, that would be pretty cool. You could imagine some conditional in the match like `((?CAPTURE)?(foo)bar|baz)` meaning that if foo is matched, that capture group will store bar, otherwise baz... While still returning the overall match. Haven't fully thought it through though. :)

Comment: @RickBrunken If you build it, they will come. ;)